# aapt fails with FontFamilyFont errors

Tags: android

Disclaimer: I'm new to Android development.

Android SDK: 7.1.1, API level 25 rev 3.

Build tools: 25.0.3

AndroidManifest.xml: `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="25" android:targetSdkVersion="25"/>`

Using dependency on the project:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
        <artifactId>support-compat</artifactId>
        <version>27.0.0</version>
        <type>aar</type>
    </dependency>
```

Building gets me (from aapt.exe):

```
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:font
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontStyle
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontWeight
```

When I change the support-compat version to 25.0.1, there are no errors.

However, I need a feature (FontRequest) from 27, and to my understanding, that's what support library is for.

Any idea why it wouldn't build? Thanks.

Comment: are you using eclipse?

Comment: @diegoveloper IDEA. But I'm building with android-maven-plugin.

Comment: try using compileSdkVersion 27

Comment: @diegoveloper you're right, this article https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd explains that compile SDK version should be at least API level of the support library in use.

Comment: This feature supported from api 26++.

Answer (score 0):

As @diegoveloper mentioned, compile SDK version must be 27, i.e. at least the version of the support library is use. More here:

https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd

However, compiling with 27 build tools doesn't work, as apparently there's a bug in IntelliJ IDEA Android plugin: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-177053

Keeping SDK 27, but falling back to 25 build tools does the trick. This only affects IntelliJ IDEA, android-maven-plugin works OK.

Comment: Well, I think it's not a bug here, what's your gradle version?, can you try  compile these dependencies with the normal way instead of maven?